# Proper way to handle variable data types in Python

Tags: python, class, types, enums

I'm trying to write a Python class `Segment`, which consists of two `Vectors` representing its points and functions relating these points.

Segments can intersect, so I'm trying to write a method, `s1.intersect(s2)`, which returns information about how Segments s1 and s2 intersect. Depending on the segments, a different number of points are required for representing the intersection:

1. No intersection -> 0 points (no particular data structure is required)
2. A single intersection -> 1 point (a single `Vector` is required)
3. A region of intersection -> 2 points (a `Segment` is required)

In other words, it seems like 2-3 data types are needed for different situations. This is inconvenient because user of the function would have to manually differentiate between them.

Here are some ways I can think of to return these data types:

- Return a list of `Vector` containing either 0, 1 or 2 items.

This would get the information across and the job done, but the returned values don't reflect the data types they are actually referring to -- namely `Vector`, `Segment`, and some notice of failure.

- Return different data types: `Vector`, `Segment`, or `False`

In this case, users would have to use `isinstance` to tell these apart or risk an invalid type problem. This is also ugly.

- Return a wrapper class, `Intersection`, that stores a `Vector`, `Segment`, or `False`.

This has the benefit of returning the same data type every time, but users would still have to use `isinstance` to differentiate between types.

What is the best way to deal with multiple return types in Python?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is ... ... you don't have to return a specific type in Python, so your `intersect()` method can return any of these based on what it determines.  In the result handling code you can use `isinstance`, `hasattr`, or something equivalent to determine what you've received.

Comment: How does the class `Intersection` fit in to this?

Comment: Wow... I forgot about `isinstance`. Basic question, sorry :/

Comment: `isinstance` is rarely needed and unlikely to be the most Pythonic answer to your question.

Comment: Why can't 2 be a `Segment` with a single `Vector`, and 1 an empty `Segment`. That way you don't need to check types at all.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I would have to override all of `Segment`'s functions to do this, since they all depend on 2 `Vector`s to work. (This also seems like a more "Java" way of doing things -- extending the class until things work out)

Comment: Sounds easier to just return a list then.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and return `None`, a `Vector`, or a `Segment`.  Those are the three possibilities, and even if you wrap it up the user will, at some point, need to deal with the differences.

So keep it simple, and let your users use `isinstance()` (which is perfectly Pythonic).